# Get Exception in thread "main" org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: Does Not Exist on running form ans script authentication using zap api

Tags: owasp, zap

public class FormAuth {

```
private static final String ZAP_ADDRESS = "localhost";
private static final int ZAP_PORT = 8080;
private static final String ZAP_API_KEY = null;
private static final String contextId = "1";
private static final String contextName = "Default Context";
private static final String target = "http://localhost:8090/bodgeit";

private static void setIncludeAndExcludeInContext(ClientApi clientApi) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ClientApiException {
    String includeInContext = "http://localhost:8090/bodgeit.*";
    String excludeInContext = "http://localhost:8090/bodgeit/logout.jsp";

    clientApi.context.includeInContext(contextName, includeInContext);
    clientApi.context.excludeFromContext(contextName, excludeInContext);
}


private static void setLoggedInIndicator(ClientApi clientApi) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ClientApiException {
    // Prepare values to set, with the logged in indicator as a regex matching the logout link
    String loggedInIndicator = "<a href=\"logout.jsp\">Logout</a>";

    // Actually set the logged in indicator
    clientApi.authentication.setLoggedInIndicator(contextId, java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(loggedInIndicator));

    // Check out the logged in indicator that is set
    System.out.println("Configured logged in indicator regex: "
            + ((ApiResponseElement) clientApi.authentication.getLoggedInIndicator(contextId)).getValue());
}

private static void setFormBasedAuthenticationForBodgeit(ClientApi clientApi) throws ClientApiException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // Setup the authentication method

    String loginUrl = "http://localhost:8090/bodgeit/login.jsp";
    String loginRequestData = "username={%username%}&password={%password%}";

    // Prepare the configuration in a format similar to how URL parameters are formed. This
    // means that any value we add for the configuration values has to be URL encoded.
    StringBuilder formBasedConfig = new StringBuilder();
    formBasedConfig.append("loginUrl=").append(URLEncoder.encode(loginUrl, "UTF-8"));
    formBasedConfig.append("&loginRequestData=").append(URLEncoder.encode(loginRequestData, "UTF-8"));

    System.out.println("Setting form based authentication configuration as: "
            + formBasedConfig.toString());
    clientApi.authentication.setAuthenticationMethod(contextId, "formBasedAuthentication",
            formBasedConfig.toString());

    // Check if everything is set up ok
    System.out
            .println("Authentication config: " + clientApi.authentication.getAuthenticationMethod(contextId).toString(0));
}

private static String setUserAuthConfigForBodgeit(ClientApi clientApi) throws ClientApiException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // Prepare info
    String user = "Test User";
    String username = "test@example.com";
    String password = "weakPassword";

    // Make sure we have at least one user
    String userId = extractUserId(clientApi.users.newUser(contextId, user));

    // Prepare the configuration in a format similar to how URL parameters are formed. This
    // means that any value we add for the configuration values has to be URL encoded.
    StringBuilder userAuthConfig = new StringBuilder();
    userAuthConfig.append("username=").append(URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8"));
    userAuthConfig.append("&password=").append(URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"));

    System.out.println("Setting user authentication configuration as: " + userAuthConfig.toString());
    clientApi.users.setAuthenticationCredentials(contextId, userId, userAuthConfig.toString());
    clientApi.users.setUserEnabled(contextId, userId, "true");
    clientApi.forcedUser.setForcedUser(contextId, userId);
    clientApi.forcedUser.setForcedUserModeEnabled(true);

    // Check if everything is set up ok
    System.out.println("Authentication config: " + clientApi.users.getUserById(contextId, userId).toString(0));
    return userId;
}

private static String extractUserId(ApiResponse response) {
    return ((ApiResponseElement) response).getValue();
}

private static void scanAsUser(ClientApi clientApi, String userId) throws ClientApiException {
    clientApi.spider.scanAsUser(contextId, userId, target, null, "true", null);
}

/**
 * The main method.
 *
 * @param args the arguments
 * @throws ClientApiException
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientApiException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ClientApi clientApi = new ClientApi(ZAP_ADDRESS, ZAP_PORT, ZAP_API_KEY);

    setIncludeAndExcludeInContext(clientApi);
    setFormBasedAuthenticationForBodgeit(clientApi);
    setLoggedInIndicator(clientApi);
    String userId = setUserAuthConfigForBodgeit(clientApi);
    scanAsUser(clientApi, userId);
}
```

}

=========================================================================================

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/319/lib/idea_rt.jar=43425:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/319/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/arpit/IdeaProjects/maven-zap-demo/target/classes:/home/arpit/Downloads/zap-clientapi-1.9.0.jar ScriptAuth
Exception in thread "main" org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: Does Not Exist
at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseFactory.getResponse(ApiResponseFactory.java:50)
at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApi.callApi(ClientApi.java:351)
at org.zaproxy.clientapi.gen.deprecated.ScriptDeprecated.load(ScriptDeprecated.java:146)
at ScriptAuth.uploadScript(ScriptAuth.java:76)
at ScriptAuth.main(ScriptAuth.java:93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to automate authentiation in ZAP is to configure and test it in the desktop, then export the context and import that via the API. If the authentication uses scripts then these will need to be registered with ZAP first.